# Visual Studio 2015 Color of selected tab

Tags: visual-studio

In VS 2015 I can change the background color of the tabs with productivity Power Tools installed, but how do I set the background color of the selected tab?

Answer (score 2):

You set the background color of the selected tab with my (commercial) [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/color-coded-tabs-in-visual-studio.html) extension:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options...->
[image]

I changed 'Selected tab' to 'VS Colors' and now I have a blue blackground color which is good to recognize.